# How to specify group id for a user-defined group

Tags: macos, user-account, unix, group

When I set up my accounts in Snow Leopard Server, I was able to give an explicit group id to my user-defined groups using the old Workgroup Manager. Now that I've updated to Mountain Lion Server, I miss that precise control.

Here is my problem: I created the following groups and group ids in
OS X 10.6 Server

```
 1025 - myteam
 1026 - workgroup
 1027 - theAteam
 9000 - zombiesquad
 9001 - hoboes
```

When I migrated to OS X 10.8 with the new Server app, my groups and group ids have all been scrambled:

```
 1025 - workgroup
 1026 - myteam
 1027 - theAteam
 1028 - zombiesquad
 1029 - hoboes
```

How do I go about setting the groups and group ids back to their prior assignment?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Workgroup Manager on Mountain Lion.  You just have to [download it](http://supportdownload.apple.com/download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/Mac_OS_X/downloads/041-6777.20120725.rfjT4/WorkgroupManager.dmg) and install it.

You can also do it using command line tools, but since you're used to Workgroup Manager, just use that.

#### Added May 2018:

In later versions of OS X, you can edit the group IDs directly from the System Preferences → Users & Groups control panel. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the group name and select "Advanced Options..." from the popup menu. That will display a form that lets you change the group ID (as well as the group name and the group UUID). *Be careful* though, as this just lets you change the mapping of number to name. Any resource associated with group ID 1025, for example, will still belong to group 1025, even if you change the group name associated with that ID. Which resources are associated with a group by ID, which by name, and which by UUID, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about downloading Workgroup Manager for 10.8.  I'd actually like to learn how to fix it on the command line, because I suspect that this is going to be a re-occurring problem, and I'd rather use the Terminal and command line to take care of it. It's also easier for us to document using the command line.

Comment: @walrus I don't know about that.  On Linux systems the command line is easy, but Mountain Lion uses Open Directory and it's more complicated than I've ever wanted to wade into.  But you can try 'man dscl' from the command line to get documentation.